# Expo-camera onBarCodeScanned works only once

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, qr-code, expo-camera

I'm trying to make an app that basically has to be able to continuously scan Qr codes. It looks something like this (unuseful parts omitted):

```js
const QRScanner = () => {

    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
    const [result, setResult] = useState('Nothing scanned yet');

    const scanHandler = ({type, data}) => {
        setScanned(true);
        setResult(data);
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            setScanned(false);
        }, 3000);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Camera
                onBarcodeScanned={scanned ? undefined: scanHandler}
            >
                <Text>{result}</Text>
            </Camera>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Unfortunatly it seems that during the execution the Camera module is able to scan a barcode of any sort only once. This should have been solved with expo's release version 45.0.6 (as shown [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/17655)) but even after the update I  have the same problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on android devices. And I have found the following three workable solutions:

**Solution 1:**

The issue has been fixed in the following version:

- "expo": "^46.0.0",
- "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",

Upgrade your expo-cli first and then upgrade expo SDK in your project:

```
 1. npm i -g expo-cli
       
 2. expo upgrade 46
```

**Solution 2:**
Replace your *expo-camera* library with *expo-barcode-scanner*. Run the following command:

```
expo install expo-barcode-scanner
```

And replace your `<Camera>` tag with  `<BarCodeScanner>`.

**Solution 3:**

Pass the `key` prop to your `<Camera>` component and update the key on `onBarCodeScanned` callback with something like this.

```
  const [isScanned, setIsScanned] = useState(false);


  <Camera
     key={isScanned ? 1 : 2}
     onBarCodeScanned={(result) => {
        handleOnBarCodeScanned(result);
        setIsScanned(!isScanned);
       }}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you have reversed the logic of toggling Scanned value in scanHandler replace it with this:

```
    const scanHandler = ({type, data}) => {
    setScanned(false); // <----- change this 
    setResult(data);
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        setScanned(true); // <----- change this 
    }, 3000);
}
```

and here:

```
 <Camera onBarcodeScanned={scanned && scanHandler} >
```